# JavaScript - get length of list options

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Is there a way I can get the length of list options in a select-dropdown HTML input tag? The list changes dynamically and I need to calculate the total number of options within the drop-down. The total options are generated dynamically, so I need a way to calculate number of option tags within an html select tag. I also need to do this in pure JS because the app I am working with will not allow me to use JQuery. (Please don't argue that with me unless there is absolutely no way to do this in pure JS.)

Needs only to be compatible with Internet Explorer.

I assume this will have to do with accessing the DOM, but I am not sure how exactly the syntax will work out.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since you didn't specify that you could use jQuery, try this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="test">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>​
```

**JavaScript:**

`​document.getElementById("test").options.length`

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wYJ3K/)**

Comment: While I was reading someone else's code just now, I noticed this person used the same `.length` method you are using, however without pointing JavaScript to the `.options` part. Is there any specific reason one should use `.options`?

Comment: I second @Barrosy's question. According to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_length.asp the ELEMENT.length serves the same purpose as ELEMENT.options.length. Could someone elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

Select the options from the select input, then count them with length

```
$("#input1 option").length
```

Answer (score 1):

i did this Using JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
      var optionLength = $("#user option").length;
      
           alert("length of options is : "+optionLength);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Get length of list Options</title>
</head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<body>
<select id="user" multiple="" size="5" class="form-control" id="participants" name="participants" style="height: 98px !important;">
  <option value="1">S RAJ</option>
  <option value="2"> SHARMA</option>
  <option value="3">SINGH</option>
  <option value="4"> ROY</option>
  <option value="5">VERMA</option>
  <select>
    <button type="button">Get Users</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is an advice about the answer provided: the solution is not giving the true value, to fix you can remove `:selected` from `var optionLength = $("#user option:selected").length;`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i removed it

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_length.asp):

In the HTML file:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

In the JavaScript file:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").length;
```

Comment: Works also with no `<option>` at all, something I was looking to control a dynamic `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="lister-sort-by-options" name="sort" class="lister-sort-by">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">
      Movies
    </option>
    <option value="1">
      TV Shows
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      Morning Shows
    </option>
    <option value="3">
      Moonlight
    </option>
    <option value="4">
      Music
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: there is no length measurement