# Creating a new element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a new `li` element using a text input. The problem is while the text is appearing, it doesn't to create an actual `li` element that I can style. The text is there, but it just forms right next to each other in a row. Here is my html:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('submit');

button.addEventListener ("click", () => {
  var taskInput = document.getElementById('task').value;
  // Creating the text for list item.
  if (taskInput === '') { // Prevents empty list item.
    alert("You have to type a task!");
  } else {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create li element.
  var text = document.createTextNode(taskInput); // Create text for list item.
  listItem.appendChild(text); // Append text to li element.
  }
  
  //Add new list item to list
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  list.appendChild(text);
  
});
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Start your list!</h1>
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="task">
<button id="submit">Create</button>
</div>
<section id="list">
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

just use `<ul>` instead of `<section>` and append to it `listeItem` and not `text`.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('submit');

button.addEventListener ("click", () => {
  var taskInput = document.getElementById('task').value;
  // Creating the text for list item.
  if (taskInput === '') { // Prevents empty list item.
alert("You have to type a task!");
  } else {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create li element.
  var text = document.createTextNode(taskInput); // Create text for list item.
  listItem.appendChild(text); // Append text to li element.
  }

  //Add new list item to list
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  list.appendChild(listItem);

});
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Start your list!</h1>
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="task">
<button id="submit">Create</button>
</div>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending `text` you need to append `listItem`. Check this out:

Your code:

```
list.appendChild(text);
```

How it should be:

```
list.appendChild(listItem);
```

Best!

Answer (score 0):

> [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section): Used to either group different articles into different purposes or subjects, or to define the different sections of a single article. [ref for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889271/5081877)

You can add the created list element to this [`<section> <ol> <li> tags`](https://jsfiddle.net/_Sam/5yhu8ueu/) at different possible positions as show below.

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create li element.
listItem.innerHTML = `taskInput`;

var list = document.getElementById("sectionlist");
list.appendChild(listItem);
```

```js
const button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener ("click", () => {
 var taskInput = document.getElementById('task').value;

 if (taskInput !== '') {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create li element.
  listItem.innerHTML = taskInput;

  var val = $("input[name='Radios']:checked").val();
    
  var list = document.getElementById("sectionlist");
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/13166249/5081877
  var listCount = $("#sectionlist li").length;
  var xpath = '//section/ol/li['+listCount+']';
  if( val == "Option 1") {
       list.appendChild(listItem);
  } else if ( val == "Option 2" ) {
   var element = document.evaluate(xpath, window.document, null, 9, null ).singleNodeValue;
   list.insertBefore(listItem, element);
  } else if ( val == "Option 3" ) {
   // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2470148/5081877
   var newElem = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(listItem);
   list.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newElem);
  }
 } else {
  alert("You have to type a task!");
 }
});
```

```css
body {margin: 2em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
span {
    /* style this span element so we can display nicely, this stlying is not neccessary */
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    /* hide the inputs */
    opacity: 0;
}

/* style your lables/button */
input[type="radio"] + label {
    /* keep pointer so that you get the little hand showing when you are on a button */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* the following are the styles */
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #efefef;
    color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    /* style for the checked/selected state */
    background: #777;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myFORM">
  <h3>Insert Element into the DOM tree at a specified position.</h3>
  <span>
 <input id="Radio1" name="Radios" type="radio" value="Option 1" checked="checked">
 <label for="Radio1">Node.appendChild() - Insert as END Ele.</label>
  </span>
  <span>
 <input id="Radio2" name="Radios" type="radio" value="Option 2" >
 <label for="Radio2">Node.insertBefore() - Insert as Last but one Ele.</label>
  </span>
  <span>
 <input id="Radio3" name="Radios" type="radio" value="Option 3" >
 <label for="Radio3">Element.insertAdjacentHTML() - Insert as Start Ele.</label>
  </span>
</div>

<h1>Start your list!</h1>
<div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="task">
    <button id="submit">Create</button>
</div>

<section id="list">
  <ol id="sectionlist">
    <li>Default list Data</li>
  </ol>
</section>
</body>
```

For more information regarding inserting element you can [refer my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33669996/5081877).

@See

- [`Element.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)
- [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)