# jQuery append with li and ul

Tags: jquery

I don't quit understand what is the different between the following four lines of code:

```
$('<li>').addClass('restaurant').appendTo('ul');  
$('li').addClass('restaurant').appendTo('ul'); 
$('li').addClass('restaurant').appendTo('<ul>'); 
$('<li>').addClass('restaurant').appendTo('<ul>');
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$('foo')` selects all elements with the tag name `foo`, whereas `$('<foo>')` creates an element with tag name `foo` ...

Comment: can you check my post. I think it may clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborated the post based on @CBroe flag.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<pre><code style="background-color: #f9f2f4;">

    $('<ul>').addClass('list').appendTo('body');

    // Doesn't do anything
    $('<li>').addClass('li1').appendTo('<ul>');
    $('<li>').addClass('li1').append('ul');
    $('<li>').append('<ul>');
    $('<li>').append('ul');

    // Working
    $('<li>').addClass('li1').appendTo('ul');
    $(".list").append("<li>");
</code></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If a string is passed as the parameter to `$( 'String Vlaue' )`, jQuery examines the provided string in 2 ways.

1. HTML snippet.
2. Selector expression.

**Selector Context**: *`jQuery()` searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a **new jQuery object** that references these elements.*

```
var jQuery_object = $( "div.foo" );
```

**Creating New Elements**: *jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with ). if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, **jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements** as described by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these elements. jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript `.createElement()` function.*

```
var html_object = $( "<p id='test'>My <em>new</em> text</p>" );
```

Create a div element (and all of its contents) dynamically and [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) it to the body element. Internally, an element is created and its innerHTML property set to the given markup.

```
html_object.appendTo( "body" );
```

---

@see

- [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)
- [jQuery: Creating a new element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186772/5081877)
- [javascript: Creating a new element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405748/5081877)
- [javascript: Add Element to document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33669996/5081877)